# the php code do not select all fields from the mysql table what is that i am doing wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, json, select

i have a php code that must select all fields **three fields** from the mysql table  but the problem that the result  is just 2 fields  how to fix this error??

mysql table "users"

fileds:

- id.
- user.
- password.
- date.

## the result is:

```
{"userlist":[{"id":"2","user":"user2"},{"id":"3","user":"michel"},{"id":"4","user":"georges"},{"id":"5","user":"testtest1"}],"success":1}
```

## this is the code

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the emp
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();


    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all emp from emp table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM users") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {


    // looping through all results
    // emp node
    $response["userlist"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        // temp user array
            $userlist = array();
            $userlist["id"] = $row["id"];
            $userlist["user"] = $row["user"];
            $userList["date"] = $row["date"];

            //$response["message"] = $userList["create_date"];


        // push single Employee into final response array
        array_push($response["userlist"], $userlist);
    }
    // success

    //$response["message"] = "DISPLAYED Success";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no emp found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No User found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: does the column `date` exist in the table users?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look closely....

```
$userlist["id"] = $row["id"];
$userlist["user"] = $row["user"];
$userList["date"] = $row["date"];
```

Notice the case of `$userlist` and `$userList`? Change the last to be lower case and it will work fine.

Comment: you save me it took me the last 2 hours it make me crazyy

Comment: holly cow how did you find the issue. I was staring at the code for long but no luck :)

Answer (score -2):

in your "while-loop" with the "mysql_fetch_array"-Statement you only pass id, user and date to the Array! (password is missing)

Comment: OP only wanted to get three fields: `must select all fields three fields...`

Comment: Sorry - unclear formulation!